# Numbering generations backwards in time (gen: 0, -1, -2, etc) within groups in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working working with a dataframe that includes different groups and that all have a range of years. Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("aaa", 3), rep("bbb", 3), rep("ccc", 3)), year = c(2016:2018))
df  

   group  year  
1  aaa    2016  
2  aaa    2017
3  aaa    2018
4  bbb    2016
5  bbb    2017
6  bbb    2018
7  ccc    2016
8  ccc    2017
9  ccc    2018
```

What I would like to do, is create a column (generation) to which a value is assigned based on the year, and in which the latest generation is generation 0 and which counts backwards for older generations. Like this:

```
   group  year  generation
1  aaa    2018  0
2  bbb    2018  0
3  ccc    2018  0
4  aaa    2017  -1
5  bbb    2017  -1
6  ccc    2017  -1 
7  aaa    2016  -2
8  bbb    2016  -2
9  ccc    2016  -2
```

I reckon it must something like the following, however this gives me a range of 1 to 3 instead of -2 to 0:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(desc(year)) %>% 
  mutate(generation = min_rank(year))
df2

   group  year  generation
1  aaa    2018  3
2  bbb    2018  3
3  ccc    2018  3
4  aaa    2017  2
5  bbb    2017  2
6  ccc    2017  2 
7  aaa    2016  1
8  bbb    2016  1
9  ccc    2016  1
```

Any ideas how to get my desired range? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `year` is not always consecutive we can `order` `year` and subtract it from total number of rows in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(generation = -(n() - order(year))) %>%
  arrange(desc(year))

# group  year generation
#  <fct> <int>      <int>
#1 aaa    2018          0
#2 bbb    2018          0
#3 ccc    2018          0
#4 aaa    2017         -1
#5 bbb    2017         -1
#6 ccc    2017         -1
#7 aaa    2016         -2
#8 bbb    2016         -2
#9 ccc    2016         -2
```

which using base R would be

```
with(df, ave(year, group, FUN = function(x) -(length(x) - order(x))))
```

---

If the `year` is consecutive always we can subtract `year` from the `max` year in the group.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(generation = year - max(year))
```

and

```
with(df, year - ave(year, group, FUN = max))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform`.

```
transform(df[order(-df$year), ], 
          generation=factor(year, labels=-(2:0)))
#   group year generation
# 3   aaa 2018          0
# 6   bbb 2018          0
# 9   ccc 2018          0
# 2   aaa 2017         -1
# 5   bbb 2017         -1
# 8   ccc 2017         -1
# 1   aaa 2016         -2
# 4   bbb 2016         -2
# 7   ccc 2016         -2
```

If the data is somewhat different, e.g. group `bbb` failure in year `2017`

```
df2 <- df[-5, ]
```

we could stick `ave` into it to get the right generation counts.

```
transform(df2[order(-df2$year), ],
          generation=factor(
            with(df2, ave(as.numeric(group), year, FUN=seq)), 
            labels=-(0:2)))
#   group year generation
# 3   aaa 2018          0
# 6   bbb 2018          0
# 9   ccc 2018          0
# 2   aaa 2017         -1
# 8   ccc 2017         -1
# 1   aaa 2016         -2
# 4   bbb 2016         -1
# 7   ccc 2016         -2
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 
    2017L, 2018L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, generation := year - max(year), group][order(- year)]
#    group year generation
#1:   aaa 2018          0
#2:   bbb 2018          0
#3:   ccc 2018          0
#4:   aaa 2017         -1
#5:   bbb 2017         -1
#6:   ccc 2017         -1
#7:   aaa 2016         -2
#8:   bbb 2016         -2
39:   ccc 2016         -2
```